# Pass big class reference to other class, performance degradation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have big main class `Core` (2k rows). I have other class `UserDefaultsStorage` responsible to store data.

The initialization of `UserDefaultsStorage` class I do in `init` of `Core`

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    self.storage = [[UserDefaultsStorage alloc]
                    initWithDefaults:[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]];
}
```

The problem is: I need to use `UserDefaultsStorage` in 5 other classes, one of them `SecondClass`. I don't want to create singleton from `UserDefaultsStorage` so I decided to pass `Core` class by reference like:

*SecondClass.h:*

```
 @interface SecondClass : NSObject    
- (id)initWithCore:(Core *)core;    
@end
```

*SecondClass.m*

```
@interface Core (Private)
  @property (nonatomic, readonly) id<UserDefaultsStorage> storage;
@end

@interface SecondClass ()
  @property (nonatomic, assign) Core *core;
@end

@implementation SecondClass

- (id)initWithCore:(Core *)core
{
  self. core = core;
  return self;
}

- (void)saveUserId:(NSString *)userId
{       
  [self.core.storage setString:userId forKey:@"some_key"];    
}


@end
```

- **Is there any performance penalty that I pass `Core` reference to 5+ classes? any risks?**
- **Is it good practice**?

Comment: What do mean "2k rows"?  Do you mean there are 2000 lines of source code?  A reference to an object instance takes the same amount of storage, no matter how big the object is. There is no performance penalty.  What you are doing here is *dependency injection* which many recommend as an alternative to a singleton

Comment: @Paulw11 `Core` class h as a lot of ivars and thank you for clarification

Comment: What _problem_ are you having with your app / code / performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing (pass by reference) is completely normal in ObjC and very cheap (the cost of a single retain, plus possibly one release; maybe an autorelease at worst). The whole point of pass by reference is that you only pass a pointer. You don't perform any copies.

2000 ivars is kind of shocking for a single class, and might suggest that you really need to split thing up in a more meaningful way, but that's entirely a separation of concerns issue (and fundamentally a maintainability issue), and has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: i think its misunderstood, i have 40 ivars and 2K of rows.